# Finding an inclusion-based path through 2-part set partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, partitions

Given $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, consider partitions of $S$ of the form $(R, R')$ where $R \subset S$ and $R'$ is $S \setminus R$, the complement of $R$ in $S$.  The goal is to list 2-part partitions of $S$ such that

1. the sequence $(Q, Q'), (R, R')$ is allowed in the list if either $Q' \subset R$ or $R \subset Q'$;
2. for each $R \subset S$, exactly one of $(R, R')$ and $(R', R)$ appears in the list; and
3. the list ends with $(S, \emptyset)$ or $(\emptyset, S)$.

Condition 2 means that there are $2^{n-1}$ 2-part partitions in a list.  Limited experimentation suggests such a list exists for each $n$.  Here is a valid list for $n = 4$:

$$ (4, 123), (12, 34), (3, 124), (24, 13), (1, 234), (2, 134), (14, 23), (\emptyset, 1234).$$

What is a nice inductive procedure or algorithm for creating such a list?  It would also be good to know if this a known problem, or equivalent to one.

Comment: It can also be described as a sequence of "ups and downs": $$4\subset 34\supset 3\subset 13\supset 1\subset 134\supset 14 \subset 1234.$$

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: strictly speaking, your suggestion of "ups and downs," and consequently your edit, is different than the literal meaning of the question as initially phrased. Nowhere did it say that for three terms in a row $(Q,Q'),(R,R'),(S,S')$, if we have $Q' \subset R$, then we must have $S\subset R'$ (or if we have $R \subset Q'$, then we must have $R'\subset S$).

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, Max's comment includes structure present in the example that is not in the problem definition, but maybe that helps narrow down the possibilities (without being too restrictive).

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev  Thanks for your observation.  My $n=5$ examples also have the additional structure you noted in the OP $n=4$ case that you modified. Here's one.  $$ 5 \subset 345 \supset 35 \subset 1235 \supset 15 \subset 135 \supset 3 \subset 123 \supset 13 \subset 1345 \supset 34 \subset 134 \supset 1 \subset 145 \supset 14 \subset S.$$

Comment: @SamHopkins: In general, it'll still be a sequence of ups and downs, just may be not alternating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a construction using [Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)

Run the standard $n-1$st Gray code backwards, getting all subsets $S_1$, ..., $S_{2^{n-1}}=\varnothing$ of $\{1,...,n-1\}$.

Replace each odd-numbered subset with its complement in $\{1,...,n\}$.

1. and 3. are straightforward.
2. follows since (a) for each subset contained in $\{1,...,n-1\}$ we have either it or its complement on our list; (b) this very same argument at the same time says that for each subset *not* contained in $\{1,...,n-1\}$ we have either it or its complement.

Comment: Thanks.  Just to show an example, the first half of the standard Gray code for $n = 4$ is $0, 1, 12, 2, 23, 123, 13, 3$ so your list is $124, 13, 4, 23, 134, 12, 234, 0$.  In terms of the original problem, that gives $(124, 3), (13, 24), (4, 123), (23, 14), (134, 2), (12, 34), (234, 1), (\emptyset, 1234)$.  In Max Alekseyev's notation, that's $124 \supset 24 \supset 4 \subset 14 \subset 134 \supset 34 \subset 234 \subset 1234$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; even cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Max Alekseyev's distillation of the problem helped me find an inductive solution.

Suppose the requested list includes $(Q, Q'), (R, R')$ with $Q' \subset R$.  It follows that $Q \supset R'$, so the same information is given by simply listing $Q, R'$.  Similarly, $Q' \supset R$ if and only if $Q \subset R'$.  Recall that $S = \{1, \ldots, n\}$.  The modified description of the requested list is then

1. the sequence $Q, R$ is allowed in the list if either $Q \subset R$ or $Q \supset R$,
2. for each $R \subset S$, exactly one of $R$ and $R'$ appears in the list, and
3. the list ends with $S$ or $\emptyset$.

Max's version of my original $n=4$ example is
$$ 4 \subset 34 \supset 3 \subset 13 \supset 1 \subset 134 \supset 14 \subset 1234. \quad (*)$$

As an aside, Max commented that this is an "up, down" sequence, to which Sam Hopkins responded that this alternating structure is not requested in the problem.  Indeed, there are solutions where the inclusions do not alternate, such as
$$ 4 \subset 34 \subset 134 \supset 14 \subset 124 \supset 24 \subset 234 \subset 1234.$$

Now for the solution.  The inductive step will be demonstrated by using the solution $(*)$ for $n=4$ to create a solution for $n=5$.  First, note that $(*)$ is a valid part of a desired list for $n = 5$ where the element 5 is in the complements of all the listed subsets.  Also, the list
$$ 45 \subset 345 \supset 35 \subset 135 \supset 15 \subset 1345 \supset 145 \subset 12345$$
with 5 included in each subset of $(*)$ is also a valid part of a desired list.  Note that the sets in $(*)$ and the new "$(*5)$" are disjoint and no subset or its complement appear in both lists.

To make a complete list for $n = 5$, reverse $(*)$ and follow it with $(*5)$, connecting the two with $4 \subset 45$.
$$ 1234 \supset 14 \subset 134 \supset 1 \subset 13 \supset 3 \subset 34 \supset 4 \subset 45 \subset 345 \supset 35 \subset 135 \supset 15 \subset 1345 \supset 145 \subset 12345.$$

Note that this construction violates the "up, down" alternation with the $4 \subset 45$ connection.  Perhaps there is a way to always build a list with the additional alternation requirement, but that was not part of the original problem.

By the way, if one starts from $1 \subset 12$ for $n = 2$ and builds from that, the resulting $n=4$ solution is
$$ 123 \supset 13 \supset 1 \subset 12 \subset 124 \supset 14 \subset 134 \subset 1234$$
which is far from alternating.